# Creating SIP application

Tags: sip, sip-server, jain-sip

I am totally new to SIP and the related technologies. I am studying about what is SIP protocol and SIP transactions. Got the basic idea.

I have a project to do where I have to create a very basic SIP service which will tell about the presence of users. It is like the app will have a DB which stores the users and their info and from a SIP phone like Xlite I will be checking the presence of the users.

I am highly confused about what to use, I mean in terms of tools, server.
I know there's JAIN SIP api which is used to develop the SIP application. What application server does it requires to deploy. Do I need a SIP server like mobicents or opensips?

I am not getting any pointers from where to start. Looking for help from the experts here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to be compliant with Presence from 3GPP standards. You can check Mobicents Presence Service at http://www.mobicents.org/sip-presence/intro.html and https://docs.jboss.org/mobicents/sip-presence/1.0.0.CR1/user-guide/en-US/html_single/. It will give you some introduction to Presence and reference material.

OpenSIPS and Kamailio are also good alternatives depending on your level of expertise.

Comment: Thanks Jean.
I have checked the Mobicents Presence Service. What I have to do is use the Database as a service. So, I can not use mobicents as is I believe. I'll have to modify the source where it communicates with DB or I can just create a basic presence service which just uses the DB as service and displays presence info. This project is just a prototype, it does not have to have all the capabilities.

Comment: Than I would recommend using SIP Servlets (https://code.google.com/p/sipservlets/) Application Server as it will allow you to handle SIP events and also Database access pretty easily. For a proof of concept that should work pretty well

Answer (score 0):

System design is all about looking at available options and making a design that fits requirements, development cost, deployment and maintenance.
Take into account the available systems at the customer site, what servers they are using etc. The JAIN SIP implementation is a toolbox for you to use, so the rest is up to you.

From the we site:

```
You can embed the JAIN-SIP stack in an applet, HTTP servlet or an application. 
JAIN-SIP can be used in SIP Proxy Servers (stateful and statelss) and in 
SIP User Agents.
JAIN-SIP has been used to build a Session Border Controller, a few Softphones, 
a Resource Adapter for the JAVA Service Logic Execution Environment, 
a SIP Servlet Implementation and in a few Test tools
```

Comment: Thanks Nilsson. This is not targeted for any company, it is just for a POC.

Answer (score 0):

JAIN-SIP is completely standalone and you can use it without other software just fine in cooperation with any DB or other APIs for Java. Note that many phones including xlite don't support normal presence servers and only do peer to peer presence. Having a server to do peer to peer is slightly more tricky since it will have to act as the peer.